# form tag inside a table ? HTML 5

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I want to ask you guys how i can put a form method "Get" in a table. In my table i have got a text field and when i submit this form it will check for validation. My validation works fine but this form doest actually submit it as i don't aget any values at the URL.

```
<form method="GET" id="my_form">
<table>
   <tr>
       <td>


<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="submit" onclick="return submitvalidation();" form="contactusform"> 
       </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: onclick you are doing something. what you are doing there ?

Comment: Kinda need the source of `submitvalidation()` to be able to help there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your submit button belongs to a different form.

Remove

```
form="contactusform"
```

Comment: yeah i have changed that to form = my_form

Comment: @user3511639 Please show source code of your validation function.

Comment: can someone help me fix this error, i have posted a new one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23493606/get-method-form-inside-a-table?noredirect=1#comment36026243_23493606